# Form input passing parameter to a wrong url

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm trying to make my form pass a parameter to a link like this :

```
index.php?action=2&parameter=value
```

Instead, all it does is pass the parameter like this:

```
index.php?parameter=value
```

This is my code :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="index.php?action=2" method="get" name="search">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="put something here...." name="search" width="100">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>
</form>
```

The form is located in my index.php?action=2 template but is passing the parameter back to the original index.php file instead of index.php?action=2 file.

I want to use the parameter later as a $_GET with few more parameters in order to search and sort the data taken from DB. The DB php code I wrote works fine, and when I create the link myself it all works nice, but not in the scenario when I try to type the search value in the textbox.

How do I avoid that ?

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

I have a switch in my index.php file which does :

```
    case 2:
    include "_template/__test.php";
    break;
```

My form is located in the above __test.php file.

Comment: Use `action="index.php"` then add a hidden input for the `action` - `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="2" />`

Comment: @Fredd: Okay, deleted my previous comment. (This one will self-destruct in a bit, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be accomplished by using a hidden field. Add the following input field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>" />
```

So, when you pass the `action` parameter, it will generate an input field with the sent value (`$_GET['action']`) and will be passed to the PHP script when the form is submitted.

Comment: Hi Amal, that's exactly what I was looking for. FDL's advise was nearly working, but it didn't assing the value so the link looked like action=&parameter=value. This one however, works perfectly fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Abbys: Glad to have been of help!